# SSIS Package (SSRS) using SQL Server Agent Failed to Generate Reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008-r2

I developed an SSIS package on my database server (ServerDB) to execute SSRS reports on another server (ServerRPT).

When I run the SSIS package using MS VS 2008 on ServerDB, the reports can be generated.

Then, I try to schedule the package on my database using SQL Server Agent, the package failed to produce the reports. File name has been created on the server but zero file size. So, the package execution is fine and problem potentially lies on the Reporting Server access.

Reporting Server (ServerRpt) has a Windows Service Account.
Database Server (ServerDB) jobs executed using SQL Server Agent Account.

Is there anything I miss out or accounts that need to be created ?

Suspect it could be permission issue on ServerRpt. 
Hope you can shed some lights.

Thanks ....

Comment: What API are you using to generate the reports? are you using C# script to use the API? I suggest you use view `ExecutionLog3` in the ReportServer database and observe differences in functioning and non functioning report executions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms159110(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I am using VB. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/jIaO1.png

Comment: Have you tried saving in a different format? Maybe something is up with PDF? When you run something in SQL Agent it is: 1. Under the SQL Agent account (or sql agent proxy) 2. Runs ON the SQL Server. If there was permissions I guess you would get no file and you'd get an error. Are there any errors in the SQL Agent log? Lastly I suggest you paste that code into your question, also the clarification about PDF

Comment: Is this _all_ your package is doing? If all your package is doing is running code then forget about SSIS and just compile a console application to do it.

Comment: The package is doing well. I saw ExecutionLog3 in ServerRPT showing rsAccessDenied. I suspect permission issue in this case.

Comment: The code is here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/jIaO1.png

The SSIS package resides on ServerDB, I would assume no permission issue to generate file on local hard disk. The permission denied should be from ServerRpt where SQL Server Agent account not able to execute it.

Comment: So start working on the rsPersmissionDenied. The ExecutionLog3 should tell which user it was. Go check if that user has sufficient report permsissions. If not grant them.

Comment: Permission part is tricky. I still can't nail down which part is blocking me. In my SQL Server Agent, it was started using Local System account. Once I change the Start Up account using my personal login, everything works perfect ! Hmm... got to figure out what's the best way to test it.

Comment: Have you established a proper service account for SQL Agent? If you want to do stuff like this you can't use Local System, and it's inadvisable to use your own account so you need to set up a service account. then you need to go into the actual report portal and grant access to this service account in there.

Comment: The part that is blocking you is the permissions against the report. Google "reporting services set up permission for a report" and read.

Comment: Found a common ServiceAccount that I can use. Replaced that to start up SQL Server Agent. Issue resolved ... thanks Nick.

Comment: No worries. Good luck